# Known issues for Weblogic 10 concurrency issues?

Tags: weblogic

Recently, our production weblogic is taking too much time to process queues. Besides investigating into queues, db queries and other stuff I thought to look into any known memory and concurrency issues in weblogic.

Does anyone know ?

Summary about the problem:
we had like 2 queues and like 8-9 clusters. one of the queues was down for some reason and the other queue started to pile up and weblogic took forever to process it. the db io increased and cpu consumptions as well.

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar production issue recently.

Check if [Flow Control](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/ConsoleHelp/pagehelp/JMSjmsconnectionjmsconnectionfactoryconfigflowcontrolparamstitle.html) is set at the connection factory level. Using this setting weblogic can throttle message production when it sees that the queue is being overloaded.

Weblogic's [checklist of things to do when you have a large message backlog](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13814/jmstuning.htm#CHDBHBGF) is useful for you to compare to your own scenarios